# CakePHP 3 Multiple isUnique allowing NULL duplicate

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have the following rule in my BlockedTable.php

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['date', 'time']),
        ['message' => 'unique error']);

    return $rules;
}
```

Up until now this has worked fine - if I try to save a new record with an already existing date and time, it prevents me from saving.

However, if my time is `NULL`, such as the below entry;

```
╔════╦══════════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║  Date        ║ Time  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ 22/08/1985   ║ NULL  ║
╚════╩══════════════╩═══════╝
```

The rule still allows me to save a new entry with the same data. So if I try to save `$date = 22/08/1985` and `$time = NULL` it saves fine and there is a duplicate record in my database. I would of expected it to have failed due to the above rule?

Why is this happening? And how can I prevent duplicate entries on `NULL` values?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If CakePHP 5 is an option for you then it is now enabled by default. [https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/15734](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/15734)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing against `NULL` using ordinary comparison operators, ie `column = NULL` (which the unique rule does), should always be `NULL` (AFAIK this is at least the case in MySQL and Postgres), thus nothing is being found, and consequently the unique check will pass whenever there is a `NULL` value involved.

If you want to prevent this behavior, you'll have to use a custom rule, as the built-in one simply doesn't support it. I think this is something worth an enhancement, so you might want to open a ticket [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues).

Here's a basic example for an overriden `IsUnique` rule class, it basically just adds a `IS` operator to the condition key, so that `NULL` checks end up as `column IS NULL`.

```
public function __invoke(EntityInterface $entity, array $options)
{
    if (!$entity->extract($this->_fields, true)) {
        return true;
    }

    $alias = $options['repository']->alias();
    $conditions = $this->_alias($alias, $entity->extract($this->_fields));
    if ($entity->isNew() === false) {
        $keys = (array)$options['repository']->primaryKey();
        $keys = $this->_alias($alias, $entity->extract($keys));
        if (array_filter($keys, 'strlen')) {
            $conditions['NOT'] = $keys;
        }
    }

    // handle null values
    foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
        if ($value === null) {
            $conditions[$key . ' IS'] = $value;
            unset($conditions[$key]);
        }
    }

    return !$options['repository']->exists($conditions);
}
```

Theoretically you could do it in an overriden `IsUnique::_alias()` method too, which would work without having to reimplement code from the original rule class, it's not really the right place though.

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.5/src/ORM/Rule/IsUnique.php**

See also

- **[Cookbook > Validation > Applying Application Rules > Creating Custom Rule objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#creating-custom-rule-objects)**

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer ndm, I'll consider my options and in the meantime create an enhancement ticket.

Comment: And just did custom rule, and working perfectly. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but, since I had to search a lot to solve this problem, I think i should post here how I did it.

In cakePHP 3.6 you can solve this problem by changing property allowMultipleNulls to false in class isUnique.

Regards.